# Using the JSON property in Angular Js to split the "Images" property using split() method

Tags: html, angularjs, json

```
var app= angular.module("myApp",[])
app.controller("ajaxCtrl", function($scope,$http)
{      
    $scope.customer=[];
    $http.get("sampledata.json").then(function(response)
    {
        $scope.customer=response.data;
    });
});
```

/*sample.json*/

```
 {
      "ProductDetails":[
      {
    "Images":     "us87_cream_mel_1.jpg|us87_cream_mel_2.jpg|us87_cream_mel_3.jpg|us87_cream_mel_4.jpg|us87_cream_mel_5.jpg",
    "ListImagePath": "https://Static05.Jockeyindia.com/uploads/dealimages/7026/listimages/",

       },
     {
    "Images": "navy-modern-brief-8044-1.jpg|8044_navy_2.jpg|8044_navy_3.jpg|8044_navy_4.jpg|navy-modern-brief-8044-2.jpg",
    "ListImagePath": "https://Static05.Jockeyindia.com/uploads/dealimages/6830/listimages/",
     }, 
   {
    "Images": "dark-assorted-checks-boxer-shorts-pack-of-2-1222-11.jpg|dark-assorted-checks-boxer-shorts-pack-of-2-1222-10.jpg|dark-assorted-checks-boxer-shorts-pack-of-2-1222-9.jpg|dark-assorted-checks-boxer-shorts-pack-of-2-1222-8.jpg|dark-assorted-checks-boxer-shorts-pack-of-2-1222-7.jpg|dark-assorted-checks-boxer-shorts-pack-of-2-1222-6.jpg|dark-assorted-checks-boxer-shorts-pack-of-2-1222-5.jpg|dark-assorted-checks-boxer-shorts-pack-of-2-1222-4.jpg|dark-assorted-checks-boxer-shorts-pack-of-2-1222-3.jpg|dark-assorted-checks-boxer-shorts-pack-of-2-1222-2.jpg|dark-assorted-checks-boxer-shorts-pack-of-2-1222-1.jpg",

    "ListImagePath": "https://Static05.Jockeyindia.com/uploads/dealimages/5993/listimages/"
     },
    ]
    }
```

I want to split the "Images" property and use it with "ListImagePath" in the ng-repeat directive. How to split it and concatenate to display?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
app.controller("ajaxCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.customer = [];
    $scope.images = [];

    $http.get("sampledata.json").then(function(response) {
        $scope.customer = response.data;
        if (response.data && angular.isArray(response.data.ProductDetails)) {
            angular.forEach(response.data.ProductDetails, function(item) {
                var images = item.images.split('|');

                angular.forEach(images, function(image) {
                    $scope.images.push(item.ListImagePath + image)
                })
            });
        }
    });
});
```

`$scope.images` will now be an array of image src links.

[Update 2]

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
app.controller("ajaxCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.customer = [];

    $http.get("sampledata.json").then(function(response) {
        $scope.customer = response.data;
        if (response.data && angular.isArray(response.data.ProductDetails)) {
            angular.forEach(response.data.ProductDetails, function(item) {
                var images = item.Images.split('|'),
                    images2 = [];

                angular.forEach(images, function(image) {
                    images2.push(item.ListImagePath + image)
                });
                item.Images = images2;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks sir 
I have a doubt the code which is you gave 
i put it inside the get() method or outside the get() method

Comment: new generated array outside of object property i access it from it is not accessible i want only "Images" property of json file split and push it on its native place so that we can access it from object like that 

`<div ng-repeat="item in ProductDetails.Image">
   <img ng-src="{{item}}">
</div>
`
i want it because i want to perform filter based on other object property.

Comment: I gave you the code to split the image as you wanted. It's very simple to just replace the images on the response with the new array.